# Transfering Ether using a contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I need to transfer ether from one account to another using solidity contract.
I am new to ethereum and solidity , so please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to send Ether (in units of wei) to an address using the transfer function of the address type of object. Using the balance property one can query the current balance of the address.

> **Example**
>   address x = 0x123;
>   address myAddress = this;
>   if (x.balance < 10 && myAddress.balance >= 10) x.transfer(10);

If x is a contract address, its code (more specifically: its fallback function, if present) will be executed together with the transfer call (this is a limitation of the EVM and cannot be prevented). If that execution runs out of gas or fails in any way, the Ether transfer will be reverted and the current contract will stop with an exception.

Refer the address type features
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html?highlight=address

Answer (score 6):

From the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/), a very basic sending contract would look something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Transfer {


    // The keyword "public" makes those variables
    // readable from outside.
    address public recipient;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    // Events allow light clients to react on
    // changes efficiently.
    event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount );


    function send(address receiver, uint amount) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        return Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
    }

}
```

Before putting your contract on the Blockchain, I recommend you to test your contract with [TestRPC](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) to simulate on your computer a blockchain.

When learning solidity, you should use [Browser Solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/) to test your contracts.

And there are also [Truffle](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/installation) and [embark](https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework) which are environments to help you developp more easily your smart contracts and interact with them through the [Web3.js API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API).

Comment: Is the `recipient` variable used in this example? And how is `balances` populated at the start, so that the contract would know how much ETH the `msg.sender` has? I'm new to Solidity as well so apologies if this is obvious. :)